# Scripting Login to Apache Server Suddenly Failing

Tags: apache, dotnet-httpclient

For some years, now, I have been using a C# program to "script" logging into FedEx's server to download my company's invoices.  The program simply mimics the URLs/Headers/Cookies/Post data that a browser normally sends in order to connect with the FedEx server, log in, "navigate" to the download page, and pull down the invoices.

Last week I started getting 401's (unauthorized) when the program makes the "Ajax" call to log in.  I have compared all my headers, cookies, and post data, and they match what a browser is sending exactly.  Somehow, their Apache server is not seeing my programmatic request the same as it sees a browser's request.  This weekend it changed from being a 401 to simply returning HTML with a message about not having permission.

I have spent a lot of time examining the fiddler inspectors on both calls (browser and code), and I cannot find anything that would trigger the Apache server to deny my program's request and not the browser's.  Both use TLS 1.2.  The browser does run JavaScript, of course, and their home page does create some cookies, but as a test I removed the JS created cookies before the ajax call on the web page (so they are not sent up and so we're both sending the same cookies -- just different values since we're returning the ones sent down from the server in different sessions), and it still authenticates with the browser.

So, my question is, what else should I be looking for to get my program to be seen like a browser other than the Request Headers (including cookies) and post data?  If anyone wants to give it a go, the home page is https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html and you can test with anything in the id/pass fields (click on the Sign In button in the upper right).  Even a fake id/pass combination comes back with JSON when using a browser (just says Success=false), whereas the programmatic call comes back with HTML with the "you don't have permission to view this webpage" error.

My program uses the HTTPClient .Net class, and I write the headers and cookies manually (I don't use the CookieContainer, since it seems to ignore some perfectly valid set-cookie's sometimes).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPClient
{
    public class Fed
    {
        HttpClient client;
        public Fed(string host)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(host);
            client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false })
            {
                BaseAddress = uri,
            };
        }

        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Application = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

        public async Task<List<byte[]>> GetBytes(string i_url, string[] i_parameters, bool i_asPost, string i_cookieContainerKey, string[] headers = null)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> a_parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            if (i_parameters != null)
                foreach (string a_parameter in i_parameters)
                {
                    string[] a_pair = a_parameter.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                    a_parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a_pair[0], a_pair[1]));
                }

            Dictionary<string, string> cookieContainer = null;
            if (i_cookieContainerKey != null)
            {
                if (Application.ContainsKey(i_cookieContainerKey))
                    cookieContainer = Application[i_cookieContainerKey];
                else
                {
                    cookieContainer = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    Application[i_cookieContainerKey] = cookieContainer;
                }
            }

            var results = await GetBytes(i_url, a_parameters, i_asPost, cookieContainer, headers);

            return results;
        }


        public async Task<List<byte[]>> GetBytes(string i_url, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> i_parameters, bool i_asPost, Dictionary<string, string> cookieContainer, string[] headers = null)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(i_url);

            HttpMethod method = new HttpMethod(i_asPost ? "POST" : "GET");
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);

            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    string[] parts = header.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(parts[0], parts[1]);
                }
            }
            if (cookieContainer != null && cookieContainer.Count > 0)
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", string.Join("; ", cookieContainer.Keys.Select(k => k + "=" + cookieContainer[k]).ToArray()));

            if (i_asPost && i_parameters != null)
                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(i_parameters);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // grab any cookies
            try
            {
                foreach (string cookieSet in response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie"))
                {
                    Cookie cookie = CreateCookie(cookieSet);
                    cookieContainer[cookie.Name] = cookie.Value;
                }
            }
            catch { }

            // Get the response content.
            HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

            Stream responseStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            if (responseContent.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
                responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            else if (responseContent.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
                responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

            List<byte[]> a_bytesArray = new List<byte[]>();
            const int c_bufferSize = 1000 * 1024;
            byte[] a_buffer = new byte[1000 * 1024];
            int a_bufferOffset = 0;
            int a_bytesAllowed = c_bufferSize;
            int a_bytesRead;

            while ((a_bytesRead = responseStream.Read(a_buffer, a_bufferOffset, a_bytesAllowed)) > 0)
            {
                a_bufferOffset += a_bytesRead;
                a_bytesAllowed -= a_bytesRead;
                if (a_bytesAllowed == 0)
                {
                    a_bytesArray.Add(a_buffer);
                    a_buffer = new byte[c_bufferSize];
                    a_bufferOffset = 0;
                    a_bytesAllowed = c_bufferSize;
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a_bytesRead + " bytes read");

            }

            // if we actually read something into this last buffer...
            if (a_bufferOffset != 0)
            {
                // it needs to be adjusted to fit only the exact amount read
                byte[] a_lastBuffer = new byte[a_bufferOffset];
                for (int a_ix = 0; a_ix < a_bufferOffset; a_ix++)
                    a_lastBuffer[a_ix] = a_buffer[a_ix];
                // and added to the array
                a_bytesArray.Add(a_lastBuffer);
            }

            return a_bytesArray;
        }

        private Cookie CreateCookie(string headerValue)
        {
            string[] parts = headerValue.Split(';').Select(v => v.Trim()).ToArray();
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie();
            for (int ix = 0; ix < parts.Length; ix++)
            {
                string[] innerParts = parts[ix].Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                if (ix == 0)
                {
                    cookie.Name = innerParts[0];
                    cookie.Value = innerParts[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    // ignore cookies that don't correctly parse
                    switch (innerParts[0])
                    {
                        case "path": cookie.Path = innerParts[1]; break;
                        //case "domain": cookie.Domain = innerParts[1]; break;
                        case "expires":
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Parse(innerParts[1]);
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        //case "max-age": cookie.MaxAge = Int32.Parse(innerParts[1]); break;
                        //case "secure": cookie.Secure = true; break;
                        //case "httponly": cookie.HttpOnly = true; break;
                    }

                }
            }
            return cookie;
        }


        public async Task Run()
        {
            string cookieContainerKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string[] headers = new string[]
            {
                "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
                "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br",
                "DNT=1",
                "Connection=keep-alive",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1",
            };


            //  Request Home page
            List<byte[]> results = await GetBytes("https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html", null, false, cookieContainerKey, headers);

            StringBuilder a_streamData = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (byte[] a_bytes in results)
                a_streamData.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(a_bytes, 0, a_bytes.Length));
            var resultsStr = a_streamData.ToString();



            string[] JSONheaders = new string[]
            {
                "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
                "Accept=application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                "Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br",
                "Referer=https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html",
                "Origin=https://www.fedex.com",
                "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest",
                "DNT=1",
                "Connection=keep-alive",
            };

            string[] parameters = new string[]
            {
                "method=isLoggedIn",
            };

            results = await GetBytes("https://www.fedex.com/etc/services/fedexlogin", parameters, true, cookieContainerKey, JSONheaders);
            a_streamData = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (byte[] a_bytes in results)
                a_streamData.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(a_bytes, 0, a_bytes.Length));
            resultsStr = a_streamData.ToString();

            parameters = new string[]
            {
                "user=xxxxxx",
                "pwd=yyyyyyyy",
                "url=#",
            };

            results = await GetBytes("https://www.fedex.com/etc/services/fedexlogin", parameters, true, cookieContainerKey, JSONheaders);
            a_streamData = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (byte[] a_bytes in results)
                a_streamData.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(a_bytes, 0, a_bytes.Length));
            resultsStr = a_streamData.ToString();

        }
    }


    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fed fed = new Fed("https://www.fedex.com");
            fed.Run().Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: To answer the question directly, there isn't anything else to check. The URL, headers, and body are pretty much all there is to an HTTP request. For anyone to be of further help, you would need to post some code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Code added.  It is a console app.  pretty mcve, but I suppose it could have been pared down some more.  It sort of fits into the framework I have, still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  They are using bot blocking software on their network.  I guess the contents of one of the cookies actually has some information about the type of software calling, and they have decided that they don't want people to script access the their own data.  Shame.